# Sycall vs int 0x80

Tags: linux, assembly, segmentation-fault, 64-bit

```
Ubuntu 16.04, intel core i5
```

I'm experementing with assembly language and wrote the following simple program:

```
section .text
    global _start

_start:
    mov eax, 0x04 
    mov ebx, 0x01
    mov ecx, text
    mov edx, 0x03
    syscall

    mov eax, 0x01
    syscall

segment .data
    text db 'The text'
```

When I compile it as follows:

```
nasm -f elf64 main.asm
ld -o bin main.o
```

and then run I got `Segmentation fault`. But when I replace `syscall` with `int 0x80` and compile ***64-bit*** binary :

```
section .text
    global _start

_start:
    mov eax, 0x04 
    mov ebx, 0x01
    mov ecx, text
    mov edx, 0x03
    int 0x80

    mov eax, 0x01
    int 0x80

segment .data
    text db 'The text'
```

It works fine and prints what I want.

If we replace only one syscall:

```
section .text
    global _start

_start:
    mov eax, 0x04 
    mov ebx, 0x01
    mov ecx, text
    mov edx, 0x03
    syscall

    mov eax, 0x01
    int 0x80

segment .data
    text db 'The text'
```

It does not Segfault, but it does not print anything as well. What did I do wrong? Why doesn't syscall work as I expect?

Comment: `syscall` uses different registers and numbers.

Comment: @Jester But I took them from linux reference. [Link](https://syscalls.kernelgrok.com/)

Comment: That's the 32 bit int 0x80 reference. Try for example [this one](http://blog.rchapman.org/posts/Linux_System_Call_Table_for_x86_64/) instead.

Comment: @Jester Perfect, thanks. Just fixed it and it works.